# Is this Matrix singular? (Gauss Jordan Method)

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

For the following Matrix

1  3  2

0  0  0

0  1  0

Would this be singular since we have a 0 in the last row last column and even if we are able to get a 1 in the second row second column's diagonal by switching row two and row three, there is no way to get that last row and last column to be 1 so it would automatically be singular?

I know there is a theorem that states even if you have a zero in the diagonal, you can fix it and make it a one by switching the row ontop of it with the row with the issue but here, there is nothing to switch.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  A matrix with a row of $0$s is singular

Comment: Thanks! and Oh right because no matter what, there is nothing you can multiply it by that would give you a 1 in the diagonal. The same olds for a column of zeros, correct?

Comment: The same holds for a column of zeros

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the Gauss Jordan method to determine that a matrix with a row of all $0$s or a column of all $0$s is singular.  Simply note that a matrix is [singular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix) if and only if its determinant is $0,$ and if in a matrix any row or column has all elements equal to $0$, then the [determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Properties_of_the_determinant) of that matrix is $0$.

Comment: Thats another good way to think about this that did not come to mind. Thank you!I see this would apply with all the scalars of a linear comination =0 as well.